# Using SVG file to fill polygon using QGIS- problem

Tags: polygon, symbology, style, svg, qgis-2.12

I try to fulfill polygon with SVG file (which created with inkscape)

[image]

but when i load the file into QGIS by this way:

[image]

i get polygon layer with no symbology:

[image]

Now, i red [Using SVG from Wikipedia to fill polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115080/using-svg-from-wikipedia-to-fill-polygon/122782#122782) but didn't succeed to fill the polygon.
When i use the option "RASTER IMAGE FILL" i get this unwanted result:

[image]
[image]

while in ArcGIS this exact symbology is very elegance:

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your svg file to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: how  can upload the file with public server?

Comment: i can send it to you if you want

Comment: I meant with services such as [File Dropper](http://www.filedropper.com/) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) etc :)

Comment: i put the file in dropbox-how can you see it?

Comment: You can post the link to your file as a comment here so that others can click and gain access to it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a26f5bhgu5nwedo/2016-06-28_114612.svg?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41754/discussion-between-newgis-and-joseph).