# Changing colors in SVG file polygon using QGIS?

Tags: polygon, color, svg, qgis-2.12

I try to change colors and lines width in this polygon (this is SVG file):

[image]

I learn from here

[SVG symbol colors differences in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199948/svg-symbol-colors-differences-in-qgis-2-12)
[Using SVG file to fill polygon using QGIS- problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200184/using-svg-file-to-fill-polygon-using-qgis-problem)
to add this line to the SVG file in order to change colors:

```
fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"
```

but the option to change the fill is blocked

[image]

How can i change the fill color?